# @Resource injection broken under spring-framework > 4.1.0

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

@Resource injection seems to behave differently between spring-framework 4.1.0 and 4.1.1 because it thinks a method in a class extended from an abstract class is a bridge and it never calls the setter.

For example

```
abstract class AbstractComponent {
    @Resource
    public void setHttpServletRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("Setting HttpServletRequest");
    }
}

@Component
public final class RealComponent extends AbstractComponent {
}
```

If I change the @Resource to @Autowired then it works as expected.

I think the change that broke this is

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/f4219ca06bbd1c324567ab9e74d0d18693359810#diff-2

It was to resolve SPR-12187

I have provided a complete spring-boot project that demonstrates the issue at

https://github.com/funkyvisions/spring-boot-hello-world

Comment: This is not a question, if you genuinely believe this to be a bug (I find the usage a little suspect and you're tangling Spring functionality with JSR specs) then there is an appropriate place to file it: https://jira.spring.io

Comment: can you use @inject instead ?

Comment: Thanks. I opened a bug with Spring https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12490. Sorry for posting to the wrong area.